# Dealing with a node-edge-node view

Tags: gui-design, mobile, tablet

I'm coding up a graph db style ([neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/)) UI for a tablet and am wondering how best to implement the actions on nodes and edges.

Actions:

- add / remove node
- link / unlink nodes (edge)
- other actions on a node (set / unset properties)

The nodes to add will come from a finite list with max one instance of each.

Have considered putting a tree / accordion on the left but am not sure where to put the list of actions for a selected node. Have also wondered about a dropdown menu on a 'selected' node but the typical node display has them moving a bit so this will get confusing. (node displays typically have 'gravity' and 'repulsion')

Lately have been considering sliding / hidden menus on the left for 'add' and on the right for 'properties / actions'. This doesn't strike me as standard though.

Does this UI make any sense? Suggestions on other avenues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give two ideas.

**(1) More direct**
When the user selects a node, show a callout with all the possible actions. It is direct, which is important as you are working with a [NUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_user_interface). Also, if it is possible, I believe you should lock the node in its position until the user takes action.

[image: Callout solution]

**(2) Less direct**
If things moves around and if you think it will be hard to do solution one, you can keep a menu on the bottom of the screen with all the possible actions. Note that the buttons are disabled and no node is selected. If the user tap on a button show a simple label above them saying "You must select a node" fading out after a few seconds.

[image: Buttons solution]

Keep all the buttons disabled until the user selects a node, then, highlight the buttons to indicate that now an action is possible.

[image]